# Select 2 people out of 10. What is the probability of being one of those people N times in a row?

Tags: probability

**Edit for clarification:**  Let me rephrase this question as: "Out of 10 people, 2 people are chosen to be winners (without replacement, i.e. you can't be chosen twice in a single trial). What is the probability that you are a winner (out of the two) ***N*** times in a row?

(Original question) Suppose I have 10 people, and for each trial, I pick 2 people to be a winner. What is the probability of a winner getting selected N times in a row given the same 10 people?

As an example, let's start with ***N = 2***. I can think of two solutions but I'm not sure which one is correct.

**Solution #1:**

$1 - \frac{8 C 2}{10 C 2}$

Explanation:

10 C 2 = number of ways to pick 2 people out of 10 on the first trial

8 C 2 = number of ways to pick 2 people on the 2nd trial, out of the remaining 8 people who were not selected on the first trial

Thus, $\frac{8 C 2}{10 C 2}$ is the probability of selecting two people on the 2nd trial in which neither of them were selected on the 1st trial

And so $1 - \frac{8 C 2}{10 C 2}$ is the probability of selecting two people on the 2nd trial in which at least one of them was also selected on the 1st trial

**Solution #2:**

This one is more intuitive but seems overly simplistic, and I'm not sure what it's calculating exactly

$(\frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{9})^2$

Explanation:

The probability of getting chosen first or second is $\frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{9}$. Raise to the power of *N* for *N* trials

Are either of these correct, and if not, what are they calculating?

Comment: Your chance of being selected in a given round is $\frac 15$  Trusting that each round is independent of all the others, the answer is then $\frac 1{5^N}$.

Comment: Your first calculation (which appears to ignore $N$)  calculates the probability that at least one of a fixed pair of people is chosen in a single round.  That is not what you were asking.  I don't think the second method computes anything in particular.

Comment: The first trial sets the targets for the rest, so the probability doesn't matter for it. For the remaining $N-1$ trials, the first two winners have $2\cdot 9-1$ chances out of $(10\ \ 2)$ to get chosen again. So $\left(\dfrac{17}{45}\right)^{N-1}$ for $N$ trials.

Comment: @lulu I think $\frac{1}{5^N}$ would be the probability of a specific person identified before the first trial winning $N$ times, whereas I think the problem allows for either person from the first trial to keep winning.

Comment: @KevinP.Barry  That's not how I read it.  "the probability of being one of the two" reads to me as saying "you are one of the $10$ people.  What is the probability that you are selected $N$ times in a row."   I don't see anything in the writing that suggests your interpretation but of course I might have it wrong.  Perhaps the OP could weigh in.

Comment: @lulu Your interpretation is correct. For clarity, let me rephrase this question as: "Out of 10 people, 2 people are chosen to be winners (without replacement, i.e. you can't be chosen twice in a single trial). What is the probability that you are one of the two winners N times in a row?

Comment: @jetvermillion   Thank you for the clarification. Do you understand my calculation?

Comment: @lulu I do, but I'm not sure I agree with it. In a given round, the chances of being selected should be slightly better than $\frac{1}{5}$ (or $\frac{2}{10}$) since the selections are done without replacement. I believe it should be $\frac{1}{10}$ (probability of being the first person picked) +$\frac{1}{9}$ (probability of being the second person picked out of the remaining 9 if you weren't the first person picked) as I suggested in Solution #2

Comment: In order to be picked as one of the two I must be picked first or second.  The probability of being picked first is $\frac 1{10}$. In order to be picked second I must fail to be picked first (probability $\frac 9{10}$)  and then I must be picked, probability $\frac 19$.  Thus the probability that I am picked second is $\frac 9{10}\times \frac 19=\frac 1{10}$.  Thus my probability of being chosen is $\frac 1{10}+\frac 1{10}=\frac 15$.

Comment: more generally, suppose we order everyone randomly.  My probability of being assigned rank $i$ is $\frac 1{10}$ for any $i\in \{1,2,\cdots, 10\}$.  Indeed, this is a consequence of the fact that all permutations are equally likely.

Comment: Should add:  if you were choosing $\textit {with}$ replacement then the answer is slightly less than $\frac 15$.  Indeed, it is $1-\left(\frac 9{10}\right)^2 = \frac {19}{100}=.19<.2$

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but to see that your calculation is wrong, suppose we extend it.  Suppose we choose $10$ people.  Then, of course, the probability that I was chosen is $1$ (since everyone is chosen).  But you get $\frac 1{10}+\frac 19+\frac 18+\cdots +\frac 11 \approx 2.93$ which is clearly not a probability.

Comment: @lulu thanks for explaining. The $\frac{1}{5}$ probability makes sense now. The follow up example of choosing 10 people is also very helpful